# ReferenceError: module is not defined after MUP deploy

Tags: javascript, meteor, mup

I'm using the latest version of Meteor (1.4.3.2), the latest version of MUP (1.2.6) and node v6.10.2 but can't get deploy to work successfully. MUP says that everything built, deployed, and started successfully but I get 502 Bad Gateway errors when connecting to my web site. Looking at MUP logs I see that there are problems downloading bcrypt during the deploy and that the app is continuously failing with the following error in mup.js:

```
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                throw(ex);
                                                ^

ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at app/mup.js:1:-27
    at app/mup.js:59:4
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
    at Function.run (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:351:11
```

The undefined "module" reference is in the mup.js file that MUP INIT builds: "module.exports = {".

Any suggestions other than don't use MUP? I'm deploying to DigitalOcean running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic, not that it should matter.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: It resolved itself. I deleted all the containers from the host, delete mup from my desktop, downloaded a clean copy of mup and everything started working. I've done several deploys since then. Make sure you are in the .deploy directory and that you are running mup.cmd if on Windows.